# My existing Keystore does not exists

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

[image]

I was updating my code for next version. After i clicked "export signed Application package", i got this error stating that my keystore does not exists. Actually i didn't delete it for sure. Now i am unable to update the app since the existing keystore vanished. Just to check whether i have deleted the file, i tried all recovery software. But unable to find. Tried all similar questions and there was no suitable result. Now please help me to recover the the old keystore.

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Why don't you make a search (starting from the /bin/ folder) and see where it is gone. It might be even the Antivirus which put it in a quarantine - check this as well.

Comment: @g00dy: Searched all drives. Even used recovery software too. Unable to find. And also couldn't find in quarantine.

Answer (score 2):

First Check out ,Where is your `key Store`exits ? at the default location or you have  stored at some where else.

**Default Path**
[image]
**Other Location**

If you are storing your `Key Store` at other location then check out that rebuild time so you will get idea.

And if there is a okay with everything the issue is about password.

So,It will be good if you `Create New Key Store` and use it

Comment: i have stored it in the app's bin folder. Tried rebuilding, keystore still not found.

Comment: once try to create new in `c:\app_keystore` and try it.Because `Bin` contatins auto generate file like `APK`,`Manifest`,`classes`.So it would be batter if you create new

Comment: @Gaan_setaglA, you should not store such files in "bin" directory my friend. `Bin` and `gen` are recreated whenever you clear and build your application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create upgrade application if you loss app's keystore.
You have to rename your package, create new keystore and publish as a new application.

There are some rules about keystore:

1. When create keystore, you have to choose expired date is greater
   than 20 years.
2. Create with password to sure that you can remember
   it.
3. Keep the keystore file you generate with Keytool in a safe,
   secure place (Best place is on Google Drive but please not
   same account that you published your app, Dropbox, Box, ... ) and never loss
   it. If you loss it, you have to do same above things.

Hope this help to remember.

Comment: Now this harsh lesson taught me the advantages of backup.